# Open the Programs with Terminal

Tags: 23.04

I installed gcc compiler and compiled a new c++ program from cpp file
To run the program I have to open the terminal and drag drop the compiled file to the terminal, but I want to run it only when double click on it, without drag and drop or write the path in terminal.

Comment: What you want is a `.desktop` file for your program. See the many examples already on your system with: `locate .desktop`, and see https://www.maketecheasier.com/create-desktop-file-linux/

Comment: Thank You so much